# Best way to query a Table in MySql

Tags: mysql

## Mode   Model

Auto    A1

Auto    B1

Manual  A1

Auto    A1

Manual  A1

Manual  A1

Manual  B1

Manual  B1

Auto    A1

I want the results like below.

## Mode    Model-A1   Model-B1

Auto            3         1

Manual      3         2

What will be the efficient way/query to get the above results?

Comment: And your inefficient method of getting this, is???

Comment: This question is as clear as black in the dark.

Comment: Maybe add your current query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to get the expected output. You can try like this as well:

```
SELECT 
   mm.Mode
, SUM((CASE WHEN mm.model = 'A1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS "Model-A1"
, SUM((CASE WHEN mm.model = 'B1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS "Model-B1"
FROM mode_model as mm
GROUP BY mm.mode;
```